# Running a node on multiple CPU cores

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, cpu, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to publish a camera stream using the "uvc_camera" (http://wiki.ros.org/uvc_camera) package. All works well, but I get a low framerate on high resolution. This seems to be due to cpu overload. When I check the cpu usage with "htop", only one core seems to be used by ROS and all the capacity is used. On the other cores however, only avout 20% capacity is used.

Is there any way to make ROS run this node using multiple cpu cores?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291355/running-a-node-on-multiple-cpu-cores/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2018-05-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. Not unless the node itself already uses/supports multithreading.

Note that this is not a ROS limitation, but a basic OS/process scheduling constraint: there is no way to split workloads in the way you ask for by the OS if the program has not been created with multi-core support already.

---

Edit: something to check: if you built the pkg from source, be sure to build with optimisations enabled. Use a CMake build type that turns those on (ie: `Release` or `RelWithDebInfo`). Packages released through and installed from the ROS buildfarm already come with optimisations.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-04-10**:
Interesting! Could you share a link to learn how to write such code? Or perhaps keywords I should search to find such resources?
Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-10**:\

> Could you share a link to learn how to write such code?

what sort of code?

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-04-10**:
multithreading/multiprocessing

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-10**:
That wouldn't really be ROS specific. Standard multi-threading can be used.

In ROS 1, one thing to keep in mind is that using a `MultiThreaded` or `Async` spinner will not automatically make callback processing multithreaded.